# django - get serializer output into another serializer

Tags: django, django-serializer

I want to get the output of one serializer 'RoomSerializer' into 'JoinRoomSerializer's fields.

I have tried to get the 'RoomSerializer' as a variable into 'JoinRoomSerializer' and then pass it in 'fields', but im getting the following error: *Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `room_extends` on serializer `JoinedRoomSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserRoom` instance.
Original exception text was: 'UserRoom' object has no attribute 'room_extends'.*

The Room model has field name and JoinRoom model has foreign key to room

My serializers:

```
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying all fields of the Room"""

    class Meta():
        model = Room
        fields = ['name']


class JoinedRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying the following fields of the joined UserRoom table"""
    room_extends = RoomSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta():
        model = UserRoom
        fields = ['room_extends', 'date_joined']
```

Comment: can you share the models file for both the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ModelSerializer` so you in Meta class you have to specify fields that your model has. I am almost sure in your case foreign key field is not named *room_extends* and this cases the error

```py
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying all fields of the Room"""

    class Meta():
        model = Room
        fields = ['name']


class JoinedRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying the following fields of the joined UserRoom table"""
    room = RoomSerializer(many=True) # name of variable same as in UserRoom model

    class Meta():
        model = UserRoom
        fields = ['room', 'date_joined']
```

Or you can use `source`

```py
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying all fields of the Room"""

    class Meta():
        model = Room
        fields = ['name']


class JoinedRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for displaying the following fields of the joined UserRoom table"""
    room_extends = RoomSerializer(many=True, source='room') # room or whatever is foreignkey field name

    class Meta():
        model = UserRoom
        fields = ['room_extends', 'date_joined']
```